# Lock down AppService with FrontDoor and AzureAD Authentication

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I would like your feedback on the following :

- For my AppServices I set Authorization with AzureAD. I get authentication page and redirection to my Appservice is fine.
- Then I setup an Azure Front Door which redirect to my AppServices as backend
- In browser when I go to https://myfrontdoortest.azurefd.net then i get the AzureAD authentication page and redirection to my AppService is a success(in browser address bar it reads https://myappservicestest.azurewebsites.net).

Now i want to secure my AppServices with FrontDoor as explained MS here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-faq. At this stage I only apply IP restrictions (not yet the X-FrontDoor-ID)

- test #1: when i go directly to my AppService like
  https://myappservicestest.azurewebsites.net then i get a 403
  forbidden access as expected.
- test #2: when I go to https://myfrontdoortest.azurefd.net then i get
  the AzureAD authentication page. I provide valid credentials and I
  noticed that i am redirect to
  https://myappservicestest.azurewebsites.net  with a 403 Forbidden.

I'm still struggling to fix it.

- Is it something i should change in the reply URL to manage IP restrictions ?
- Is it something i should change in FrontDoor configuration ?

Your help is very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the front door does not have a fixed IP, it is not feasible to set the IP settings in the webapp.

[image]

So it is recommended that you still use the official recommendation to add rewrite rules in the xml file.

[image]

The article you are looking for is very useful. It is recommended to read it carefully. If you have any questions, you can also raise a support ticket, MS will give you good answer.

I also find this issue, you can refer it.

[image]

[How do I lock down the access to my backend to only specified instance(s) of Azure Front Door? #36141](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/36141)

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. Do you have any idea on why after giving my credentials it still returns a 403 ?

Comment: @terry Will you encounter it after the xml file is modified?

Comment: @terry The official document describes it very clearly. When all the configurations take effect, only your front door is allowed to access the webapp. It is recommended to recheck after modification.